# Erase partition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

It's my again, I was trying to solve my problem of dual boot in Ubuntu, because in the Grub I didn't have windows to boot. So the community sent my into this link "How can I change/convert a Ubuntu MBR drive to a GPT, and make Ubuntu boot from EFI?"

I was trying to follow the steps to do it, I wanted to use the flashdrive where was installed Ubuntu to boot since windows. So erase a file, I shuttled down and Ubuntu sent error message and when I restart the system I have windows on my screen and I was scare. Please community, what do you think that I must do? Erase the partition where is Ubuntu in Windows and install Ubuntu again? or return to Ubuntu and make Ubuntu boot from EFI? I don't have CD driver to make a backup.

[My question was](https://askubuntu.com/questions/862828/partitions-after-dual-boot/862837?noredirect=1#comment1333446_862837)

Comment: If you want to dual boot, boot with uefi enabled and reinstall ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you bodhi.zen so I don't modify anything, because I have the impression that the partition was little for Ubuntu. When I wanted donwload in Ubuntu I always have a message saying not enough space on the disk.

Comment: Follow the install guide and make space. If Windows is uefi you will need to install ubuntu with uefi as well. see http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi